# Same tree verification through recursive tree traversal

Tags: python, binary-tree, traversal

I've prepared a recursive tree-traversal based solution to the ["same tree" problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/). However, I'm encountering an error on use cases involving None values. Why is my approach incorrect and how should I be altered to handle the use case?

```py
class Solution(object):
    
    def traversal(self,root):
        visited = []
        
        if root:
            if root.left:
                visited.extend(self.traversal(root.left))

            visited.append(root.val)

            if root.right:
                visited.extend(self.traversal(root.right))   
            
        return visited             
    
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        """
        :type p: TreeNode
        :type q: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
    
        p_path = self.traversal(p)
        q_path = self.traversal(q)
        print(p_path, q_path)
        return p_path == q_path
```

Use case: input([1,1][1,null,1]), output(true), stdout([1,1], [1,1])

Answer (score 1):

Two different trees can have the same in-order traversal, but different structure, so it's not sufficient to completely rely on "traversal" in your code.

Hint: trees are only the same if they have the same root and (recursively) the same left subtree and (recursively) the same right subtree.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on the recursive attempt, but an iterative one worked.

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):             
    
    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        """
        :type p: TreeNode
        :type q: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        stack = [(p,q)]
        while stack:
            p_curr, q_curr = stack.pop()
            
            # both p and q exist
            if p_curr and q_curr:
                
                # validity check
                if p_curr.val != q_curr.val:
                    return False
                
                # left check
                if p_curr.left and q_curr.left:
                    stack.append((p_curr.left, q_curr.left))
                elif p_curr.left and not q_curr.left:
                    return False
                elif not p_curr.left and q_curr.left:
                    return False
                
                # right check
                if p_curr.right and q_curr.right:
                    stack.append((p_curr.right, q_curr.right))
                elif p_curr.right and not q_curr.right:
                    return False
                elif not p_curr.right and q_curr.right:
                    return False                
                    
            
            elif p_curr:
                # only p exists, invalid
                return False
            
            elif q_curr:
                # only q exists, invalid
                return False
        
        return True
```